# aircrack troubleshoot: install either libnl1 or lbnl3

Tags: aircrack-ng, kali, airmon-ng

I know this question has been asked before but I have tried many things and none worked like:

`sudo apt-get install libnl-3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev`

Which did not update or remove anything. I have the latest version of aircrack. I am running ubuntu on a vm. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are your trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to install aircrack and use airmon-ng. When I ran cd `path of the aircrak` and then `make` the above error pops up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install it via APT:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng
```

Then you can run it with:

```
sudo airmon-ng
```